# Java 16.0.1, Jshell.... no text visible when entering commands in CMD

Tags: jshell

I have Java 16.0.1 installed on my windows 10 laptop.
I am going into the command prompt and launching jshell. This starts correctly and displays the correct version.
However, anything i type is not visible on the command prompt. If i press CNTR+C the text s then displayed but i cannot execute the command.

I have tried installing java 11.0.11 and am facing the same issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe related; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654406/cant-paste-into-jshell-version-11-0-11-reproduced-on-two-machines